# How do I consistently find the color picker in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In draw.io, when I try to change the color of an element sometimes I've seen just boxes with set colors in them, with the option to write in a specific color code. Other times I've seen a color picker interface with a brightness selection, etc. that allows me to more easily select a custom color. I haven't been able to pin down why I sometimes get one and sometimes the other.

How do I get the color picker interface to always appear?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Sorry, @alihaider, I didn't and stopped using draw.io. I didn't want to deal with the cookie issues I was having.

Comment: @alihaider Does [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62943/how-do-i-consistently-find-the-color-picker-in-draw-io/168780#168780) help you?

Comment: +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Although not ideal, as a work around for the moment you can use your browsers built in web tools:

[image]
([gif source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46857594/7607701))

Answer (score 1):

For me, the color picker works perfectly. Draw.io version 20.7.4:

[image]